# Unable to connect to Remote Desktop using Auto IT Script

Tags: java, autoit, remote-desktop

Please help,While connecting to Remote Desktop using java,displaying "The logon attempt failed" but manually it is able to connect.

I'm using `AutoItX` class, Object

Below is the my tried code to connect:

```
@Test
public void openRunWindow() throws AWTException {

    object.robotkeyPress(KeyEvent.VK_WINDOWS);
    object.robotkeyPress(KeyEvent.VK_R);
    object.autoitWinWaitActivate("Run");
    System.out.println("Run window is open");
    object.robotkeyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_R);
    object.robotkeyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_WINDOWS);
    object.autoitSendKeys("mstsc");
    System.out.println("Mstsc is entered");
    object.robotkeyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    object.autoitWinWaitActivate("Remote Desktop Connection");
    System.out.println("Remote Desktop Connection window is open");
    object.robotkeyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    object.autoitSendKeys("ipaddress");
    System.out.println("Remote Desktop Connection - Ip address is entered");
    object.robotkeyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    object.robotkeyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    object.autoit.winWaitActive("Windows Security");
    System.out.println("Windows Security is open");
    // Enter Password
    object.autoitSendKeys("password");
    object.robotkeyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    object.robotkeyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);

    // Press Enter on More Choices link
    try {
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Try to copy password and username, and paste them!
Then, it will work!
It seems you are sending keys but they do not match the actual keyboard characters even though they are same in appearance.

Comment: this question shouldn't be tagged "selenium"